# can I convert String to Boolean in @ComponentScan::lazyInit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dynamic-properties

In `application.properties`:

```
app.lazy_init=true
```

and in `Main` class ：

```
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = "${app.lazy_init: false}")
public class Main(){...}
```

But the `lazyInit` is a `Boolean`, how can I convert a `String` to a `Boolean` in `@ComponentScan::lazyInit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `lazyInit` is typed as a `boolean` so the value that you configure it with has to be a `boolean` at compile time. In other words, there's no opportunity for converting the `String` to a `boolean` as that conversion has to be performed at runtime.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks!